# how to do Rx Observable on Silverlight Webclient

Tags: silverlight, system.reactive

I would like to use Rx in my SL app. I want to set up an observable on my REST requests to my webserver. I dont see how to wire up Observable.FromEvent or Observable.FromAsync. My best guess is to make Webclient completion fire an event and then do Observable.FromEvent. IS there a better way?

Comment: +1 I'd like to see some one demonstrate what the looks like ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, this is the best way to make a web request in Rx.

```
public IObservable<WebResponse> MakeWebRequest(
        Uri uri, 
        Dictionary<string, string> headers = null, 
        string content = null,
        int retries = 3,
        TimeSpan? timeout = null)
{
    var request = Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        var hwr = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        if (headers != null)
        {
            headers.ForEach(x => hwr.Headers[x.Key] = x.Value);
        }

        if (content == null)
        {
            return Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(hwr.BeginGetResponse, hwr.EndGetResponse)();
        }

        var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        return Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Stream>(hwr.BeginGetRequestStream, hwr.EndGetRequestStream)()
            .SelectMany(x => Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[], int, int>(x.BeginWrite, x.EndWrite)(buf, 0, buf.Length))
            .SelectMany(_ => Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(hwr.BeginGetResponse, hwr.EndGetResponse)());
    });

    return request.Timeout(timeout ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)).Retry(retries);
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
MakeWebRequest(new Uri("http://www.google.com"))
    .Subscribe(
        x => Console.WriteLine("Response is {0}", x),
        ex => Console.WriteLine("Someone Set Us Up The Bomb: {0}", ex.Message));
```

Comment: thats going to take some time to absorb!

Comment: Don't worry about the implementation, just know that you're passing in the info to make a web request, and you're getting an IObservable<WebResponse> that will return one item eventually (the response). In this case, IObservable<T> represents a "Future", kind of like Task<T>

Comment: Can you also include example usage code including error handling?

Comment: so whats the reason for most Observable.Foo returning IObservable but OBservable.FromAsync returns a Func that returns an IObservable?

Comment: Because it's giving you a Func that will issue a new request every time you call it, just like if you called BeginXXXX. It's "translating" the Begin/End into an Rx-friendly syntax

Comment: Hmm, what about the content parameter?