# webclient returns unknown error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient, system.reactive, caliburn.micro

I have a simple scenario where my app makes an async web request for xml file (mock for webservice).

Everything seems ok but webclient always returns UnknownError.

What am I missing here?

Here is the web request code:

```
public void LoadNews()
{
    // to prevent caching append random string to uri
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Uri uri = new Uri(FeedUri +"?rnd="+rnd.Next());

    WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();


    var o = Observable.FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(wc, "DownloadStringCompleted")
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
        .Select(s => s.EventArgs.Result)
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Dispatcher)
        .Subscribe(r =>
            {
            // use caliburn.micro eventaggregator to publish message
            EventAggregatorHelper.EventAggregator.Publish(new NewsPostMessage(LoadNewsPosts(r)));
            }, () => { });

    wc.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}
```

Here is the helper class:

```
public class EventAggregatorHelper
{
    static EventAggregator _eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
    public static EventAggregator EventAggregator
    {
        get { return _eventAggregator; }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to access the webservice via a tool like fiddler? A little debugging of the request/response process if possible would help a lot.

Comment: Just installed wireshark and captured the traffic. Requests goes out to server and response comes back ok.

Comment: I installed wireshark and captured the traffic. Response and request work as they should.

Comment: It seems that DownloadStringCompleted event is raised **before** webclient gets the real response. Kinda defeats the purpose of using RX.

Comment: DownloadStingCompleted event is always raised with error. There must be some stupid coder error that I didn't notice.

Comment: this resolved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421945/how-to-do-rx-observable-on-silverlight-webclient